# What size threaded insert for a bolt that measures ~.35"?

Tags: fastener

I need a threaded insert that fits a bolt that measures .35" / 8.9mm in diameter on my calipers. Including the threads. I can't find my bolt size tester and don't have time to run to the hardware store to use theirs / test it because it's far away. Anyone know what I should buy? M9 inserts/nuts don't seem to be a thing. Nor 11/32...

And yes I know the threading pattern is another consideration...

Comment: A picture of the bolt might help.  Those sizes are not showing up on size tables.

Comment: M9 exists, but isn't *common.* McMaster (just a happy customer) has some (but not many) parts and tools for that size. *e.g.* https://www.mcmaster.com/products/nuts/ https://www.mcmaster.com/products/taps/thread-size~m9/

Comment: They have one 11/32"-24 nut available. So that's also uncommon, but not non-existant.

Comment: This may be crazy,  Since you have to buy the insert, why not use a more common size bolt and an easy to find insert that matches. like 3/8 or 10mm

Comment: @RMDman  That takes all the fun out of it and how are we suppose to 9mm or 11/32 nuts/bolts do exist.